# Umbraco How to read content items using ASP.NET MVC Partial View and Razor

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I have some special document type in Umbraco and in content tree I have one item that contains sub-items with this document type.
 I don't want to use VS 2012.
 and I want to create some partial view for read this items.
 and create some html markup.
 I created, partial view via umbraco UI,

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<dynamic>
```

How to read all item and subitems in my view just with Umbraco API ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should inherit from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage` in your partial view:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
```

Then pass into your partial the current model:

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartialName", Model.Content)
```

Then in your partial you can just the API to get the children or whatever your [query](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/querying) is:

```
@foreach (var node in Model.Children().Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "YourDocTypeAlias")
{
   <p>@node.Name</p>
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer has been accepted, in Umbraco 7.1 (might not be the target version which OP was using), you cannot inherit anything when a model is used. Is this a new thing with Umbraco? (attached screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/v9ozlCX.png of using a model at the same time as inheriting)

Comment: This works in 7.1 too. Your inherits should be the full path: `@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage`